# How to fix the few incorrect outputs in this Arabic transliterator?

Tags: javascript, nlp, arabic, transliteration

Specifically I am stuck on the `al-` which you commonly see on Arabic words, like [al-Qiblatayn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masjid_al-Qiblatayn). Here is the transliterator which I have made, you can for the most part ignore the [exact output](https://github.com/mountbuild/ovo/blob/62cee1230e22cf42aacec59b5948054b7a7a717d/form.js#L435) syntax, just note that the meaning of each character in the output has a specific meaning, and doubling a letter means making a vowel long or geminating a consonant.

```js
const m = {
  '\u0626': "'y",
  '\u0624': "'w",
  '\u064E\u0627': 'aa',
  '\u0650\u0649': 'ii',
  '\u064E\u0649': 'aa',
  '\u0650\u064A': 'ii',
  '\u064F\u0648': 'uu',
  '\u064A\u064E': 'ay',
  '\u0648\u064E': 'aw',

  '\u0649': 'aa',

  'ء': "'",

  'ا': 'aa',
  'ﺍ': 'aa',
  'ﺎ': 'aa',

  'ب': 'b',
  'ﺏ': 'b',
  'ﺐ': 'b',
  'ﺒ': 'b',
  'ﺑ': 'b',

  'ت': 't',
  'ﺕ': 't',
  'ﺖ': 't',
  'ﺘ': 't',
  'ﺗ': 't',

  'ث': 'c',
  'ﺙ': 'c',
  'ﺚ': 'c',
  'ﺜ': 'c',
  'ﺛ': 'c',

  'ج': 'dj',
  'ﺝ': 'dj',
  'ﺞ': 'dj',
  'ﺠ': 'dj',
  'ﺟ': 'dj',

  'ح': 'h~',
  'ﺡ': 'h~',
  'ﺢ': 'h~',
  'ﺤ': 'h~',
  'ﺣ': 'h~',

  'خ': 'H',
  'ﺥ': 'H',
  'ﺦ': 'H',
  'ﺨ': 'H',
  'ﺧ': 'H',

  'د': 'd',
  'ﺩ': 'd',
  'ﺪ': 'd',

  'ذ': 'C',
  'ﺫ': 'C',
  'ﺬ': 'C',

  'ر': 'r!',
  'ﺭ': 'r!',
  'ﺮ': 'r!',

  'ز': 'z',
  'ﺯ': 'z',
  'ﺰ': 'z',

  'س': 's',
  'ﺱ': 's',
  'ﺲ': 's',
  'ﺴ': 's',
  'ﺳ': 's',

  'ش': 'x',
  'ﺵ': 'x',
  'ﺶ': 'x',
  'ﺸ': 'x',
  'ﺷ': 'x',

  'ص': "s\"",
  'ﺹ': "s\"",
  'ﺺ': "s\"",
  'ﺼ': "s\"",
  'ﺻ': "s\"",

  'ض': "d\"",
  'ﺽ': "d\"",
  'ﺾ': "d\"",
  'ﻀ': "d\"",
  'ﺿ': "d\"",

  'ط': "t\"",
  'ﻁ': "t\"",
  'ﻂ': "t\"",
  'ﻄ': "t\"",
  'ﻃ': "t\"",

  'ظ': 'C',
  'ﻅ': 'C',
  'ﻆ': 'C',
  'ﻈ': 'C',
  'ﻇ': 'C',

  'ع': "'",
  'ﻉ': "'",
  'ﻊ': "'",
  'ﻌ': "'",
  'ﻋ': "'",

  'غ': 'r~',
  'ﻍ': 'r~',
  'ﻎ': 'r~',
  'ﻐ': 'r~',
  'ﻏ': 'r~',

  'ف': 'f',
  'ﻑ': 'f',
  'ﻒ': 'f',
  'ﻔ': 'f',
  'ﻓ': 'f',

  'ق': 'K',
  'ﻕ': 'K',
  'ﻖ': 'K',
  'ﻘ': 'K',
  'ﻗ': 'K',

  'ك': 'k',
  'ﻙ': 'k',
  'ﻚ': 'k',
  'ﻜ': 'k',
  'ﻛ': 'k',

  'ل': 'l',
  'ﻝ': 'l',
  'ﻞ': 'l',
  'ﻠ': 'l',
  'ﻟ': 'l',

  'م': 'm',
  'ﻡ': 'm',
  'ﻢ': 'm',
  'ﻤ': 'm',
  'ﻣ': 'm',

  'ن': 'n',
  'ﻥ': 'n',
  'ﻦ': 'n',
  'ﻨ': 'n',
  'ﻧ': 'n',

  'ه': 'h',
  'ﻩ': 'h',
  'ﻪ': 'h',
  'ﻬ': 'h',
  'ﻫ': 'h',

  'و': 'w',
  'ﻭ': 'w',
  'ﻮ': 'w',

  'ي': 'y',
  'ﻱ': 'y',
  'ﻲ': 'y',
  'ﻴ': 'y',
  'ﻳ': 'y',

  'آ': "'aa",
  'ـآ': "'aa",
  'ٱ': '',
  'ﺁ': "'aa",
  'ﺂ': "'aa",

  'ة': 'at',
  'ـة': 'at',
  'ﺓ': 'at',
  'ﺔ': 'at',

  'ال': 'al',
  'ـى': 'aa',

  'ﻻ': 'laa',
  'ﻼ': 'laa',

  'ﲓ': 'iim',
  'ﳰ': 'iim',
  'ﳝ': 'iim',
  'ﱘ': 'iim',

  'ﲅ': 'lm',
  'ﳭ': 'lm',
  'ﳌ': 'lm',
  'ﱂ': 'lm',

  'ى': 'a',
  'ﻯ': 'a',
  'ﻰ': 'a',

  '،‎': ',',
  '؟': '?',
  '؛': ';',
  '۔': '.',
  '﴾': '{',
  '﴿': '}',

  '\u064e': 'a',
  '\u0650': 'i',
  '\u064f': 'u',
  '\u0627': 'aa',
  '\u064a': 'ii',
  '\u0648': 'uu',
  '\u064b': 'an',
  '\u064d': 'in',
  '\u064c': 'un',

  'گ': 'g',
  'ڨ': 'g',
  'ڭ': 'g',
  'چ': 'j',
  'ڥ': 'v',
  'ڤ': 'v',
  'پ': 'p',

  '\u06e1': '',
  '\u0652': '',

  '\u0651': '',

  '\u0670': 'aa',
  'إ': "'i", // Arabic Letter Alef With Hamza Below
  'أ': "'",
  '\u200e': '', // ltr marker
  ' ': ' ',
}

const generate = (s) => {
  let out = []
  let i = 0
  let r = s
  let last
  while (r.length) {
    let found = false
    x:
    for (let k in m) {
      if (r.indexOf(k) === 0) {
        let v = k == '\u0651' ? last.split('').pop() : m[k]
        last = v
        i += k.length
        out.push(v)
        r = r.substr(k.length)
        found = true
        break x
      }
    }
    if (!found) {
      throw `oops ${out.join('')} from ${s}, ${r.codePointAt(0).toString(16)}`
    }
  }
  return out.join('')
    .replace(/ii+/g, 'ii')
    .replace(/ee+/g, 'ee')
    .replace(/aa+/g, 'aa')
    .replace(/oo+/g, 'oo')
    .replace(/uu+/g, 'uu')
}

console.log(generate('ٱلْكَعْبَة‎'))
console.log(generate('اَلْمَسْجِدُ ٱلْحَرَامُ‎'))
```

Here are the outputs of a few of them:

```
ٱلْكَعْبَة‎,lka'baat
اَلْمَسْجِدُ ٱلْحَرَامُ‎,aalmasdjidu lh~ar!aamu
ٱلْمَسْجِد ٱلْأَقْصَىٰ‎,lmasdjid l'aKs"aa
الحرم الشريف,aalh~r!m aalxr!iif
مسجد القبلتين,msdjd aalKbltiin
```

Notice (1) and (3) one starts with `l-` instead of `al-`, and 2, 4, and 5 start with `aal-`. Also (tangent note), the first one ends in `-t` even though the word is normally written [Kabaa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaaba) with no `t`.

Why is the `al-` written in two different ways from what I am seeing here (copied these words from Wikipedia). And how do I fix the generator so it writes it properly (a short `a` sound it seems, rather than a long `aa`)?

*If you notice anything else wrong I would love to know, this is just what I have found in getting started so far. If you know some general things I am missing from this implementation please let me know. I have included the "Arabic Shadda U+0651" to double a consonant, and everything else I got from the Wikipedia [Arabic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet) page.*

I am not that familiar with reading Arabic, but I notice some of the vowel diacritics are different in the two sets, just not sure why or how to resolve it.

Comment: Why not check for the "al" first before anything else. It is normally at the start of the word but not always.